# WPF showdialog Textbox with var content

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

I try to get the following done:

A WPF application where i have multiple buttons where you can set a notification message.
Depending on the button, you can set different messages.

What i did, was on the message button i have put this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    CounterMessage msgOne = new CounterMessage();
    msgOne.ShowDialog();
 }
```

This will open op a new WPF window here only is a textbox and an exit button.
On exit in this message window, it will save the message to a parameter.

But here is the trick.
I want to use this message window for multiple notifications, and it will display in the textbox any text content if there is already any on a string in the application.

So for example:
In the main app i have button A and B to set the notification on.
I click on button A, the showdialog pops up and in the textbox already have "you clicked button A"
If it was button B that has been clicked, it should display "you clicked button B"

So i should sent some extra info with the ShowDialog, so i can use the messagewindow for each one.
Could someone help me out a bit herE?

I must say i find it a bit hard do decently discribe what i want, so i hope i made myself clear enough.

EDIT
So hat i want is showing the content of a string parameter (to be exact: Properties.Settings.Default.XXX) into the textbox that is in the Countermessage window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you want something like this.  I am assuming that CounterMessage is a Window, and that there is some binding mechanism or property that displays what the message is.

```
public class CounterMessage : Window
{
    public CounterMessage(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Your button event would then be something along the lines of:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = sender as Button;
     CounterMessage msgOne = new CounterMessage(btn.Text);
     msgOne.ShowDialog();      
}
```

The point being that you don't send something to the ShowDialog method, but rather to the class that is the dialog itself.  I also assume that the dialog does more than just displaying the message - otherwise, you would just use `MessageBox.Show(....)`

Comment: no what i want is showing the content of a string parameter (to be exact: Properties.Settings.Default.XXX) into the textbox that is in the Countermessage window

Comment: Ok, so pass that into the class instead.  The point is, you can't pass something in the ShowDialog call - you need to pass something to the underlying class (window).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Debug.WriteLine(btn.Name);
```